# Data is not inserted into the SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am developing a project and I have a difficulty in the part of SQL Server, I created a procedure, and I need that when the value hum in the table `Bi_medicao` is greater than 10 he put that line in the other table `Bi_alerta`but the the problem is that when I run the code everything is fine, but when I see it it doesn't put anything in the table ... Just don't add any rows to the `Bi_alerta` table.

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bi_alertainset] 
    @alerta_hum varchar(50),
    @alerta_temp varchar(50),
    @alerta_lpg varchar(50),
    @alerta_co varchar(50),
    @alerta_fumo varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @alerta_hum = med_hum,
        @alerta_temp = med_temp,
        @alerta_lpg = med_lpg,
        @alerta_co = med_co,
        @alerta_fumo = med_fumo
    FROM 
        Bi_medicao

    IF (@alerta_hum > 10)
        INSERT INTO Bi_alerta (alerta_hum, alerta_temp, alerta_lpg, alerta_co, alerta_fumo)
        VALUES (@alerta_hum, @alerta_temp, @alerta_lpg, @alerta_co, @alerta_fumo)
END
```

Comment: Does your table, `Bi_medicao` *really* only ever contain one row?

Comment: Also, please learn to make *good* use of whitespace; code that is all left aligned is often very difficult to read, and it is difficult to tell where one statement/block starts and another ends.

Comment: my "Bi_medicao" table doesn't have just one, I have a C # program that puts data there, and if the humidity is higher than 10, it puts that line in the "Bi_alert" table too ...

Comment: Then what do you think syntax like `SELECT @alerta_hum = med_hum FROM Bi_medicao` will do? `@alerta_hum` is a **scalar** variable; it can store *one* atomic value. If your table, `Bi_medicao` has many rows, then the value assigned to `@alerta_hum` will be just *one* of them not all of them, and which value will be completely arbitrary due the lack of an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: type of @alerta_hum is varchar(50), are you trying to compare the lenght of the value or implicitly trying to compare with '10' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be that @alerta_hum is Varchar and not INT. Either you change the declaration to INT or you CONVERT your @alerta_hum
Also, I would recommend using BEGIN/END for IF as well.

```
IF (CONVERT(INT, @alerta_hum) > 10)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Bi_alerta (alerta_hum, alerta_temp, alerta_lpg, alerta_co, alerta_fumo)
    VALUES (@alerta_hum, @alerta_temp, @alerta_lpg, @alerta_co, @alerta_fumo)
END
```

If that still doesn't work, you should check if you variables are all asigned after the reset with Bi_medicao. Simples way would be to insert some PRINT Statements like PRINT @alerta_hum

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to reproduce without any sample data, table structure and so on. Anyways, I would suggest to modify the insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Bi_alerta (alerta_hum, alerta_temp, alerta_lpg, alerta_co, alerta_fumo)
SELECT med_hum, med_temp, med_lpg, med_co, med_fumo
  FROM Bi_medicao
  WHERE CAST(med_hum AS INT) > 10
```